# Automatically generate plain text emails from html emails when using inky?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-6, premailer, inky

I watched a few online tutorials and set up [inky](https://github.com/foundation/inky-rb) and [premailer](https://rubygems.org/gems/premailer-rails/versions/1.9.2) to give styling to emails in an organised way, and am very happy with this set up.

premailer gem should automatically generate the `text.erb` email based on the `html.erb` email. According to [here](https://makandracards.com/makandra/61772-auto-generating-plain-text-bodies-for-html-e-mails-in-rails-apps) that should still work when using inky, but when I visit my mailer in the browser and select the 'View as plain-text email' option, I see the regular booking_confirmation.text.erb file with whatever I put in it manually, rather than the booking_confirm.inky file's body.

How can I get premailer to generate the plain text email based on the `.inky` file?

#### Notes:

- Useful premailer info: https://makandracards.com/makandra/61772-auto-generating-plain-text-bodies-for-html-e-mails-in-rails-apps
- Tutorial on inky + premailer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lUFgOiYP9yM

Answer (score 0):

After randomly playing about with different extensions and other things, I realised it's simple: premailer/inky will only generate the plain text equivalent of the HTML file **if** a file of that name with extension `.text.erb` **doesn't** already exist.

In other words, to get a auto generated version of `booking_confirmation.inky`, you simply need to delete `booking_confirmation.text.erb`, then it will auto generate.